# React useEffect keeps fetching even after stating my dependency

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, json-server

I'm having infinite fetch on my json-server with my useEffect even after I put my dependency for re-rendering after submitting task. It does re-render but in my console I see that it keeps fetching get request. What seems to be lacking on my code. Thank you

```
function TodoListComponent() {

const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
const [nameOfTask, setnameOfTask] = useState('')

const url = `http://localhost:3002/todos`

const addTodo = () => {

const task = {nameOfTask}

  fetch('http://localhost:3002/todos', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"Content-type" : "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify(task)
  })
  setnameOfTask('')
}
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setTodos(data))
}, [todos])


return (
<div>
  <div className='head-container'>
    <div className="input-container">
      <input type="text" value={nameOfTask} onChange={(e) => setnameOfTask(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={() => {
        addTodo()
      }}>add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="todo-container">
        {todos.map(todo => (
            <div key={todo.id} className="todo-list">
                <p>{todo.nameOfTask}</p>
            </div>
        ))}
  </div>
</div>
)
```

Comment: You are reacting on `todos ` in your `useEffect`, but you are setting it in the same useEffect, hence the infinite loop. Remove the todos from the dependency array

Comment: but when i put an empty dependency array my list wont re-render with the new added todo

Comment: You need to set the todo state in the addTodo function with the new todo.

Comment: now I see, that's why it keeps looping. thank you very much, im very much new to react thank you for clearing it up